# XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage duplicate entry - XMPP MUC

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, xmpp, xmppframework

I am using XMPPFramework for iOS to implement group chat (MUC) with default core data (XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage).

I am able to send and receive messages between two devices.

```
self.xmppRoom = //Get room instance;
[message addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:[self.xmppStream generateUUID]];
[self.xmppRoom sendMessage:message];
```

XML Format:

```
<message><request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request><body>{
  "mediaItem" : "0",
  "body" : "Sending Message 1"
}</body><thread>2012C10A-6CAD-4C29-86BD-D93334FA74C8</thread></message>
```

when i send a message, in XMPPMessageArchiving.sqlite database, i can see two entries of same message (outgoing 1 - and outgoing 0).

[image: Outgoing Message]

As you can see above, thread id is same and the outgoing is 0 and 1 indicate incoming(received) and outgoing(sent) message.

Question 1:
Is this the expected behavior of XMPPMessageArchiving core data to save both incoming and outgoing message?

If Yes, then i think i have to fetch only outgoing message (ZOUTGOING = 1) from this database and display on the screen. Is this correct?

---

Whenever i quit and re open the app or reestablish the connection (XMPPStream) and enter into the room (`[self.xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:[self.myJID user] history:nil];`), i am getting the same message that i sent earlier, with incoming value as 0. This will happen every time i re establish the connection. How can avoid it.

[image: Duplication]

If i receive a message from another user, it will be added in this database with outgoing as '0'. How can i filter incoming message which is sent by another user and my sent message (Fig 1).

Message stanza:

```
<message id="5CF46E24-BF92-48AC-B13D-A1D7B4B45942" to="hmgroup@conference.local0094.local" type="groupchat"><request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"/><body>{
  "mediaItem" : "0",
  "body" : "Sending Message 1"
}</body><thread>2012C10A-6CAD-4C29-86BD-D93334FA74C8</thread></message>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, for the MUC duplicate messages.  You should go for `XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage` but not `XMPPMessageArchiving`. Personally I don't like the behavior that `XMPPMessageArchiving` also handles MUC messages.

Second, by default a MUCRoom will send some history to newly joined user, the number is determined by config, under `mod_muc: history_size:`.  You can set it to 0 to disable this feature.

Comment: Thanks. Now i am using XMPPRoom storage to get the message of room. But here some time  (once) i got the duplicate message.